# How to access a complex object from a Dao with Room?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

Let's take an example to illustrate my problem.

my Entity :

```
@Entity(tableName = "pokemon_table")
data class Pokemon(@PrimaryKey
        @ColumnInfo(name = "id")
        val id: Int? = 0,
        @ColumnInfo(name = "type")
        val type: Type? = null)
```

According to Room, if i want to insert a complexe Object like `Type`, i have to use a TypeConverter :

```
    @TypeConverter
    fun fromType(typeContent: Type?): String? {
        if (typeContent== null) {
            return null
        }
        val gson = Gson()
        val type = object : TypeToken<Type>() {

        }.type
        return gson.toJson(typeContent, type)
    }

    @TypeConverter
    fun toType(typeStr: String?): Type? {
        if (typeStr == null) {
            return null
        }
        val gson = Gson()
        val type = object : TypeToken<Type>() {

        }.type
        return gson.fromJson(typeStr, type)
    }
```

How can I access to a property of `Type` from the `PokemonDao` ?

I have tried this but i can't use `type.id` in the Query because `type` is a json :

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM pokemon_table WHERE type.id = :typeId")
fun getPokemons(typeId: Int): LiveData<List<Pokemon>>
```

Comment: Type should be a String representing a JSON so you can use LIKE to search inside that String.

Comment: I have that in the `pokemon` table and the `type` column : `{"id":0,"element":"fire"}`

Comment: You think I can access the `type.id` from the query? I'm not very comfortable with SQLite

Comment: You can search on that type column like this ```@Query("SELECT * FROM pokemons WHERE type LIKE '%"id":' || :typeId || ',%'")``` this will give you the pokemon row with the type column deserialized into the object property.

Comment: Will add it as an answer just in case someone needs it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are serializing your `Type` to a **json** formated String, you should use `LIKE` to search inside that string on you query:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM pokemons WHERE type LIKE '%"id":' || :typeId || ',%'")
fun getPokemons(typeId: Int): LiveData<List<Pokemon>>
```

This will return the requested row with the Type column deserialized again.